# How to see which component called the handler in ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, components, frontend

Currently I have two ember input boxes which both call the same onInputChange handler function.

```
{{ input .... action("onInputChange") }}
{{ input .... action("onInputChange") }}
```

I'm wondering how the onInputChange can determine which component actually called it. (Each one needs to do something specific).

Is there a more "ember" way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Closure actions could curry arguments. You could use that one to provide the necessary context information to your helper. E.g. `{{input on-input=(action 'onInputChange' row)}}` would call `onInputChange()` action with the value of `row` as first argument. For more details you could have a look [in the guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/templates/actions/#toc_action-parameters) and [API documentation](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/release/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/action?anchor=action).